# multiple instances of same foreign key field in same form

Tags: django, django-models

I have a record keeping system that consists of two models. One model creates a holding page and the other creates individual entries...

```
class RecordEntry(models.Model):
    client = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CLIENT_CHOICES)
    job_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
    cell_number = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    entry_title = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name, blank=True, null=True)
    ...     

class RecordPage(models.Model):
    client = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CLIENT_CHOICES)
    job_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    job_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
    create_date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    entry = models.ForeignKey(RecordEntry, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

…where the page might be #211211
and the individual entries might be #211211-01, #211211-02, #211211-03

For simplicity, I'm using the forms rendered in admin to create the pages. It's convenient because the admin gives me the "plus" icon that allows me to create and add an entry on the fly. My problem is, I'd like to be able to add as many "entries" to the page as I need. I mean, to get multiple "entry" fields on a form I could do something like:

```
class RecordPage(models.Model):
    client = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CLIENT_CHOICES)
    job_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    job_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
    create_date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    entry = models.ForeignKey(RecordEntry, blank=True, null=True)
    entry2 = models.ForeignKey(RecordEntry, related_name='+', blank=True, null=True)
    entry3 = models.ForeignKey(RecordEntry, related_name='+', blank=True, null=True)
    entry4 = models.ForeignKey(RecordEntry, related_name='+', blank=True, null=True)
    entry5 = models.ForeignKey(RecordEntry, related_name='+', blank=True, null=True)
    entry6 = models.ForeignKey(RecordEntry, related_name='+', blank=True, null=True)
    entry7 = models.ForeignKey(RecordEntry, related_name='+', blank=True, null=True)
    and so on…
```

but there has to be a better way, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't use ManyToManyField here

```
entry = models.ManyToManyField('RecordEntry', related_name='pages')
```

And Django admin will automatically gives you the ability to add new rows.

Comment: because, unless I'm misunderstanding the way ManyToMany fields work, I believe the admin widget will not only give me the ability to add entries, on every form instance, it will render a list of ALL of the RecordEntry objects... which could literally be thousands

Comment: @kjarsenal If thats concern, may be then you can look at _limit_choices_to_.

Comment: @kjarsenal if you define an extra = 1 on the inline admin it will only list the related objects plus one. It will not list ALL the objects in your DB. But yes they will be available as a dropdown in the choice which might makes things slower, however that issue also occurs in your code above. The best war around this is using row_id and autocomplete with JS.

Comment: "The best war around this is using row_id and autocomplete with JS."
could you expound on this just a bit. This may be the direction I need to go in but I'm unsure what implementation of the "row_id" solution would look like.

Comment: @kjarsenal take a look at http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html this will help speeding up your admin site as it will avoid generating huge drop down lists. Although I believe this should be a separate question to comply with the spirit of SO.

Comment: your answer pointed me towards a solution to my issue, which is all I could ask and for which I am appreciative. thank you.